# In Tkinter how can I get the cursor position(line, column) from the text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, cursor

I want to get the cursor position(line, column) from the text widget and print it using the button.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def click():
    print('line and column')#print location
    
    
    
button=Button(root,text="click",command=click)
button.pack()

text=Text(root)

text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the documented `index` method, giving it the index "insert". It will return a string in the form of *line.character*.

```
def click():
    (line, char)= text.index().split(".")
    print(f"line: {line} char: {char}")
```

Answer (score 0):

We should add an index id to `text.index` - so the updated version of Bryan's example is:

```py
(line, char) = text.index(tk.CURRENT).split(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `INSERT` and `text.focus()` So you can  see cursor at the end of sentence.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def click():
    print('line and column')#print location
    text.insert(END, 'line and column')
    text.focus()
       
button=Button(root,text="click",command=click)
button.pack()

text=Text(root)

text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]